# Transversing an Array of structs error in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, struct, runtime-error

Current code:

```
const int MAX_CODENAME = 25;
const int MAX_SPOTS = 5;

struct Team  {    
string TeamName[MAX_CODENAME];  
short int totalLeagueGames;  
short int leagueWins;  
short int leagueLoses;  
}; 

//GLOBAL VARIABLES:
 Team league[MAX_SPOTS];


void addTeams(){
int i = 0; //first loop
int j; //second loop
while(i < MAX_SPOTS){
    cout << "****** ADD TEAMS ******" << endl;

    cout << "Enter the teams name " << endl;
    scanf("%s", league[i].TeamName) ;
}

void searchTeam(){

   string decider[MAX_CODENAME];
   cout << "Please enter the team name you would like the program to retrieve: " << endl;
   cin >> decider[MAX_CODENAME];

for(int i = 0; i < MAX_SPOTS; i++){

    if(decider == league[i].TeamName){

        cout << endl;
        cout << league[i].TeamName << endl;

        break;
    }else{
        cout << "Searching...." << endl;
    }



}
```

}

I really dont know why its not working but I have included all the perquisite header files such as  and  but the program crashes when i enter the data and then attempt to search. I get the circle of death and then  *program not responding*  then says  *Process returned 255 (0xFF)* . It does not even out put  *Searching....*  the program practically gives up as soon as I enter that name.

Also if this can be optimized by the use of pointers that would be great.

tl;dr run-time error causing the search to fail as soon as i type in a name. And for the record I have checked to make sure the name I entered is valid.

Comment: if the size of your array is `MAX_CODENAME`, then the last element is at index `MAX_CODENAME - 1`

Comment: `string TeamName[MAX_CODENAME];  ` creates an array of strings. I would think a team would only have one name: `string TeamName;` (Assuming `string` is `std::string`)

Comment: Use iostreams, not scanf. Use std::vector, not arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` doesn't know about `std::string`. Use `std::cin >> league[i].TeamName`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `TeamName` member variable:

```
string TeamName[MAX_CODENAME];
```

is an array of 25 strings, so in this line:

```
scanf("%s", league[i].TeamName) ;
```

you are courrupting the array. You don't really want an array anyways, so change the `TeamName` declaration to:

```
string TeamName;
```

and then when you read the name, you'll need to use `iostream`s which knows how to populate a `string` type (scanf only works with c char arrays):

```
std::cin >> league[i].TeamName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%s", league[i].TeamName) ;
```

This should be changed to

```
std::cin >> league[i].TeamName ;
```

A couple of other things here....

```
string decider[MAX_CODENAME];
       cout << "Please enter the team name you would like the program to retrieve: " << endl;
       cin >> decider[MAX_CODENAME];
```

Every time you input a value, you are telling the computer to hold the inputted value at decider[25] but the computer only reads indexes 0-24.

```
if(decider == league[i].TeamName){
```

Which array slot are you comparing the team name to? If its the 25th element than the statement should be

```
 if(decider[24] == league[i].TeamName){
```

Pointers are better suited if the number of TeamNames are unknown. Based on the limited code presented, I highly recommend you stay within the realm of basic data types. For the purposes of troubleshooting, please post your full code in the future.